# Two questions on indexing and regression

Tags: regression, time-series

1. Is it OK to have causals indexed on different base years? Amongst many references, I think the answer is “no”. Is that true? *p.360 Wooldridge [[Introductory Econometrics: A Modern Approach, 5th ed]](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1111531048).* says you should have a common base year. Just google… “common base year” regression and you will see loads of support.
2. Is it OK to have the Y variable as an index based on 100? For example  100 ,98, 103, 101, etc.

Comment: This question (especially the second part) is rather abstract, which makes it seem vague: would you be able to give an example to clarify it?

Comment: I guess familiarity with economics is being assumed, and by index @Tom Reilly means something like an index of prices, wages, etc.

Comment: can you also specify the page of the book?

Comment: @Tom You're probably looking for a more substantial answer, so I will just leave this as a comment. For ease of interpretation, it seems like using a common base year is almost always the best thing to do. That said, there's no reason to suppose that it couldn't be done otherwise. The results would probably be a bugger to try to interpret, though. Compare apples with apples, not apples with oranges, right? Regarding the second question, I see no reason as to why the Y variable (dependent variable) could not be an index.

Comment: Graeme, Thank you so much for your response.  

I posted this question on a few linkedin groups and cross validated.  The answers were in favor of using the data "as is".  The only issue is that the interpretation of the model (ie beta weights) which could be remedied by easily making the base year common.  Thanks to Graeme Walsh on Cross Validated, John Totten on Marketing Science, Jeff Werling and Maria Cuitino on Macroeconomic Research.